# Bytes to KiloBytes

Tags: iphone, filesize

I am retrieving the size of all files in the document directory. I am using the method `attributesOfItemAtPath` to do so. It is successful. But I am getting the output in the form of bytes and of class `NSNumber`. It does'nt look good.

So, I need to get the output in KBs or MBs and I have to convert them into `NSString` in order to store that in a `NSDictionary` as I have to display it in a TableView. Please help me to do so. Thank you.

Here is my code..

```
directoryContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *path in paths){
filesDictionary  =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
filesSize = [[NSNumber alloc] init]; 
filesSize = [filesDictionary objectForKey:NSFileSize];
filesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:filesSize, @"filesSize", nil];
[directoryContent addObject:[filesDictionary copy]];
}
```

And I am using the following code to bind the size in tableView which is not working.

```
cell.lblSize.text = (NSString *) [[directoryContent objectAtIndex:listIndex] objectForKey:@"filesSize"];
```

Help me to convert the size of a file from byte to KiloByte and to display it in a tableView.
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rounded to the nearest KB:

```
NSNumber *fileSize = [[directoryContent objectAtIndex:listIndex]
                      objectForKey:@"fileSize"];
cell.lblSize.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",
                     (int)round([fileSize doubleValue] / 1024]);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use my NSValueTransformer subclass if you like:

```
@interface FileSizeTransformer : NSValueTransformer {

}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass;
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation;
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value;

@end

@implementation FileSizeTransformer
+ (Class)transformedValueClass;
{
    return [NSString class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation;
{
    return NO;
}
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value;
{
    if (![value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        return nil;

    double convertedValue = [value doubleValue];
    int multiplyFactor = 0;

    NSArray *tokens = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B",@"KB",@"MB",@"GB",@"TB",nil];

    while (convertedValue > 1024) {
        convertedValue /= 1024;
        multiplyFactor++;
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f %@",convertedValue, [tokens objectAtIndex:multiplyFactor],value];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is nice!  I'd add a range check after the while loop -- just in case you're faced with a petabyte file :)

Comment: Good snippet! I've made a category for NSString with it <3

Comment: Note: If you add localizations to your app, the tokens aren't always the same. I.e. MB is MO in french.

Comment: By the way it should be 'while (convertedValue >= 1024) {'

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `NSNumber` instead of `NSString` to store numbers in an `NSDictionary`.