# Is there a NSValueTransformer for file sizes?

Tags: cocoa, uitableview, nstableview, nsvaluetransformer

I can't believe something like this doesn't exist already.  Is there some code out there that implements NSValueTransformer for file sizes?  I'd like a column in my table view to display file size in the closest [SI binary multiple](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html), for example "1.4MB" instead of "1,468,006".

The closest thing I can find is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195419/bytes-to-kilobytes) but the answers aren't really what I'm after.

Comment: https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit - but library recommendations are off topic for SO.

Comment: More code by @mattt!  Alas this doesn't contain a file size formatter though.

Comment: TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter in this library does exactly what you want, I think?

Comment: Of course - thanks for pointing it out.  I managed to miss it on my first and second pass through.